# How long until I can reapply after refusal of a UK Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, standard-visitor-visas, peruvian-citizens

I am a Peruvian permanently resident in Australia. I have lived in Sydney for 27 years and want to travel to the UK to visit some friends. I applied online but my application was refused. I put a friend as a contact as I was planning to stay with him for a few days then maybe stay in different places.

The decision was that I didn't provide evidence of my friend's personal circumstances and that it was unclear I had a friend in the UK to visit. *This mas my mistake as I only asked for his information, not a referral or invitation letter*.

The other point was evidence of my financial circumstances. It was a bank letter and that showed the balance on one day but not the financial commitment of an applicant nor the source of funds in my account. I am a bit confused with this one as I don't know what to show.

Do they want six months of bank statements with all my transactions?

Isn't that going to be a lot of paper to print and send?

I also sent additional information such as my itinerary for the flights already purchased and a letter from my employer confirming the time I was going to be away (1st - 18th October).

So I don't know what to do.

Can I reapply with additional information?

Because the flight is quite close, what kind of extra information can I show to ensure the application is approved?

This refusal caught me unguarded. I didn't know this was going to happen as it is just a simple holiday. When I applied (14 August) I hadn't planned much and bought the ticket because it was cheap but they asked so many questions about where I was going to stay I just asked my friend for his address, as I was planning to stay there for a few days but for the others I wasn't sure - maybe look for places in Airbnb or similar.

I have recently acquired Australian citizenship. I just need to wait a few months to make the official pledge and I can apply for an Australian passport. I think with that I don't need to apply for any visitor visa. But that's not going help me with the flight booked for October.

What should I do?
Can I reapply?
Postpone everything?

Answer (score 1):

> The decision was that i didn't provide evidence of my friend's personal circumstances and is unclear if i have a friend in the UK to visit.

Why did you provide your friend's contact ? As you provided it, UKBA would require evidence of his financial circumstances and that he is a legal alien in UK. Did you try to apply under Family visit visa ?

It would have been easier if you had applied for a genral visitor visa

> When you apply you’ll need to provide:

- a current passport or other valid travel identification
- 2 passport size colour photographs
- evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, eg bank
  statements or payslips for the last 6 months details of where you
  intend to stay and your travel plans - you shouldn’t pay for
  accommodation or travel until you get your visa
- You need a page in your passport that’s blank on both sides for your
  visa.

You’ll need to provide a certified translation of any documents that aren’t in English or Welsh.

[Check the UKBA websites for guidance.](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration)

> because the fly is quite close

You can forget about flying, if you don't have the time to reapply. Did they mention you could appeal ? If yes then do appeal, as appealing shows you were a geniune case and botched up. They may take a lenient view if you decide to reapply or while considering your case. The decision for appeal timelines are around 3 months or so, but maybe less, as UKBA is quite bureaucratic.

But before appealing check out what are the costs involved. Sometimes it maybe better to reapply then appeal. And as you are applying for a tourist visa and not settlement, rather than appealing it would be worthwhile to reapply. Better reapply and provide all the documents mentioned on the UKBA website.

For Australian citizens, from UKBA website :-

- You won’t need a visa to come to the UK. However, you should bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border.